# Rendering react component conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I cant figure out for the life of me why only one of my 73 unit tests are failing

```
            sendToSwiftAction = (
                <Button
                    text={buttonText}
                    buttonType="primary"
                    onClick={this.toggleModal}
                    disabled={
                        !canSendToSwift || swiftCommitEnabled
                            ? sendToSwiftStatus !== 'NOT_SENT'
                            : sendToSwiftStatus === 'COMPLETED'
                    }
```

It seems that !canSendToSwift is being returned as false somehow in my unit test

```
        const btn = render(null, { permissions: [] }).find('Button');

        expect(btn.prop('disabled')).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

The test was passing just fine until i added the toggle swiftCommitEnabled ? true flow : false flow logic. It was just !canSendToSwift || sendToSwiftStatus !== 'NOT_SENT' when it was passing. Am i missing something simple? Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: FIXED: was being evaluated in a bad order added parenthesis around swiftCommitEnabled ternary statement `(swiftCommitEnabled ? sendToSwiftStatus !== 'NOT_SENT' : sendToSwiftStatus === 'COMPLETED')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is going to evaluate the binary expression first (`||`)  and then the ternary (`?:`). Your code is read as this:

```
const condition = !canSendToSwift || swiftCommitEnabled
const disabled = condition
  ? sendToSwiftStatus !== 'NOT_SENT'
  : sendToSwiftStatus === 'COMPLETED'
```

Or if it's easier to understand in purely binary logical operations:

```
const condition = !canSendToSwift || swiftCommitEnabled
const case1 = sendToSwiftStatus !== 'NOT_SENT'
const case2 = sendToSwiftStatus === 'COMPLETED'
const disabled = (condition && case1) || (!condition && case2)
```

Comment: Okay so i think i understand what your saying is its determining true before it even gets to the ternary (which in turn switches it to false because its passing the !== 'NOT_SENT' condition?)

Comment: Sorry if i'm hard to understand :D react/JS is super new to me my last few years has been spent strictly backend python/c#/java.

Comment: Yes probably. I wasn't sure what your issue was exactly, but this is what jumped at me as error prone.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations of a way to determine the disabled button behind those multiple conditions <-- the button text and notification are working correctly using that same ternary. only difference is they aren't evaluating !canSendToSwift prop

Comment: I was thinking about just adding 2 separate OR conditions but, that just seems messy ie... `disabled={!canSendToSwift || !swiftCommitEnabled && sendToSwiftStatus === 'COMPLETED' || swiftCommitEnabled && sendToSwiftStatus !== 'NOT_SENT'`

Comment: when a condition starts to look messy like this, you can always decompose it in several `const` or even in its own function. And if you're going to mix `||` and `&&`, unless you're sure you know which one take precedence over the other (like multiplication and addition), you should use parentheses.

Comment: Okay I gotcha, the intent is to decompose of the toggle completely once the new flow/feature is complete end-end but, until then we are just kinda building behind the toggle while maintaining the original functionality.